# Use Mid-point Rule with $ \ m=n=2 \ $ to approximate the integral $ \ \iint_R f(x,y) dxdy \ $

Tags: functions, numerical-methods

A contour map is shown for a function $ \ f \ $ on the square $ \ R=[0,2] \times [0,2] \ $ .

Use Mid-point Rule  with $ \ m=n=2 \ $ to approximate the integral $ \ \iint_R f(x,y) dxdy \ $

[image]

**Answer:**

With $ m=n=2 \ $ , the square $ R=[0,2] \times [0,2] \ $ have been divided into the following Four sub-squares :

$ [0,1] \times [0,1] \ $,

$ [0,1] \times [1,2] \ $,

$ [1,2] \times [1,2] \ $,

$ [1,2] \times [0,1] \ $

The Mid-ponits are  $ \ (1/2,1/2) , \ (1/2,3/2) , \ (3/2, 1/2) , \ (3/2, 3/2) \ $

**Now, I have the confusion in finding the values of $ \ f \ $ at these points**:

**I think**,

$ f(1/2, 1/2) \approx 27 , \\ f(1/2,3/2) \approx 0 , \\ f(3/2,1/2) \approx 14 \\ f(3/2,3/2) \approx 15 \ $

**But I am not sure .**

**I need help finding the above values .**